# Which Informatica transformation can be used to save a JSON file to a database or a .csv file?

Tags: java, json, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Below will be first session using curl command

```
start-->command task(output file in .json)
```

Above file should be converted to .csv or later should be loaded to database.

Comment: you dont have any direct transformation. You need to use transformation for unstructured data ( separate license needed). Or you can use java transformation to purse the json data.

Comment: so you mean we need to use a java transformation ? how we send this file to java transformation like a string in single port and convert this string into .csv file?

Comment: some guidance here- https://network.informatica.com/thread/85846

Comment: Think about using some bash / Python script. This might actually be easier.